# MainActivity context Android

Tags: java, android, android-activity

I need to fetch the MainActivity context and call getIntent() to process the intent that started the Activity.

Due to some reasons, I don't want to do this in my MainActivity (that would have been a simple getIntent() in any non-static method of the class).

The MainActivity's instance will be exposed (somehow) and with that object, I need to invoke getIntent().

There's the following way:

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {
  
  // Store the activity context
  private static Activity activityContext;

  public void onCreate() {
    activityContext = this;
  } 

  public static Activity getActivityContext () {
    return activityContext;
  }
}
```

But is there any other way to get the MainActivity context? Like a direct func to the Activity's instance instead of capturing the instance and exposing a method as shown above..

Comment: It looks like your problem lies in your structure. Your `Intent` shouldn't be used out of the context of the `Activity` that supplies it.  `Activities` are not static in themselves so relying on a static reference that may or may not exist upon retrieving is a bad practice through and through.  The question is why are you attempting to access it in a static context? `Due to some reasons,` what are the reasons?

Comment: NEVER put an Activity in a static variable.  It creates a massive memory leak.  And you can't rely on there being only one instance of an Activity, so doing this is going to lead to invalid results anyway.  If you need to use the intent in another class, get it in the activity and pass it to where it needs to go.

Comment: @avalerio, I have native libs and they have their own thing to do. I want to process these intents after that.

Comment: @GabeSechan What memory leaks are you talking about? I'm only capturing the already instantiated activity?. "And you can't rely on there being only one instance of an Activity, so doing this is going to lead to invalid results anyway. " - Okay, I understand.

Comment: I understand the problems with storing in a static variable...an activity may get instantiated twice. 

So, the suggested method (and best practice) is, to do a getIntent inside the onCreate and process it there itself. Is that correct?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Retrieve the `Intent` in `onCreate`, pull everything you need out of it and then you can store it in a number of places.

`SharedPreferences` or a `Database` or `Static Variables` or a `Singleton`

When you finally need the `Intent` data you can pull it from a place that is more permanent, instead of an `Activity` which is not.

Comment: Similar to this, there may be many other DO's and DONT's. Do you know any place where a newbie can be made aware them all? I followed the documentation of Activity but didn't know that you were not supposed to do this.

Comment: Seeing you are already using native libs you might have jumped right into the deep end. It's really about separation of concerns. `Activities/Fragments` are considered the `Views` in `Android`.  That `Intent` is data, data doesn't belong in a `View`, only displayed in it.  As for using static context, `Android Studio` should have been giving you a lint warning, don't ignore it. Static instances are typically frowned upon in general in programming, so using it should have been the last thing you tried. Just try to write clean code, if your uncertain ask a question here.